# Quickbooks install Error: 1603

Tags: windows-8, flash, adobe-flash, activex, quickbooks

Trying to install Quick books simple start on Windows 8 but I keep getting a Flash/ActiveX error right after entering the product key. Any thoughts?

**Screen shots of the errors:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnMC8.jpg

Windows 8 already has .NET 4.5 built in, and Flash is up-to-date...

Here was the QB support advice: http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/SLN41780

We tried the recommendations in the above article without any success.

Comment: have you installed the required MSXML 4.0 Sp3?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and MSXML4.0Sp3 was downloaded and accepted no errors but on trying to install Quick Books same error messages. :)

Comment: inside the temp folder there should be a MSI log. Open it and look for error messages.

Comment: Here's the line in the log with the error: MSI (s) (5C:2C) [16:55:36:336]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX. Product Version: 10.0.32.18. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Adobe Systems, Inc.. Installation success or error status: 1603.

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the complete log: http://pastebin.com/Xu2j8K70

Answer (score 0):

adobe flash player setup fails. Win8 includes a Flash player and the tool doesn't know this and fails. [MS doesn't list all versions as compatible](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win8&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=Quickbooks&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14).

If you need the tool run it inside a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox, VMware Player with a Windows XP for example)